# How to import a module in python from a folder named com.apple.demo?

Tags: python

I have to name the single folder as `'com.apple.com'`, it has an `app.py` under the folder. 
I want to import the `app.py` using `importlib`, how to do that?

I have tried using following code, but always got an error.

The structure of folder:

```
--com.apple.com

----app.py
```

and code:

```
importlib.import_module("com.apple.com.app")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: For (future) questions: "*but always got an error.*". What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use **sys** and codes are as follows.

a.py:

```
def p():
    print "hello world"
```

b.py:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('C:***\\com.apple.com') 
import a

a.p()
```

output:

```
hello world
```